# phpunit test function in interface

Tags: php, unit-testing, interface, phpunit

Still learning how to test php

I now have a working interface (I think) - one of the functions is intended to create a series of records which I now want to test that is does. I admit I know very little about testing and so have more questions than knowledge.

So

My interface currently looks like this:

```
interface TicketCreatorInterface {

public function createTicket($input, $book);

}
```

My 'repository' class looks like this:

```
Class TicketCreator implements TicketCreatorInterface {

protected $ticket;

public function __construct(TicketAudit $ticketAudit)
{
    $this->ticket = $ticketAudit;
}

public function createTicket($input, $book) {

    $counter = $input['start'];

    while($counter <= $input['end']) {

        $this->$ticket->create(array(
            'ticketnumber'=>$counter,
            'status'=>'unused',
            'active'=>1
            ));

        $this->ticket->book()->associate($book);

        $counter = $counter+1;

    }

    return $counter;



}
```

And my attempts at a test looks like this:

```
public function testCreateCreatesTickets(TicketCreatorInterface $ticketCreator) {

    //arrange
    $book = Mockery::mock('Book');


    //act
    $response = $ticketCreator->createTicket(array('start'=>1000, 'end'=>1001), $book);

    // Assert...
    $this->assertEquals(true, $response);
 }
```

I tried first without typehinting the interface as without that I got an error of no object. I tried creating an instance on the interface but you can't do that so resorted to typehinting in the function

The error I get when I run the test is:

```
Argument 1 passed to TicketCreatorTest::testCreateCreatesTickets() must implement interface TicketCreatorInterface, none given
```

Creating interfaces is a new approach to me so don't yet understand all about it.

So how can I test this function does create a ticket as expected?

I've tested models with sqlite in memory database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the your TicketCreator in your test to call the method on.  Change your test to this:

```
public function testCreateCreatesTickets() {

    //arrange
    $book = Mockery::mock('Book');
    $ticketAudit = Mockery::mock('TicketAudit');
    $ticketCreator = new TicketCreator($ticketAudit);


    //act
    $response = $ticketCreator->createTicket(array('start'=>1000, 'end'=>1001), $book);

    // Assert...
    $this->assertEquals(true, $response);
 }
```

Since you require a TicketAudit in your constructor, you will need to create a mock of that object also and pass it in to your constructor.

The only times that PHPUnit provides arguments to a test case is when you have a Data Provider or the tests depends on another test.

http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers

http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.examples.StackTest2.php

Keep in mind that you don't create an instance of an interface.  If I want to make sure your object implements an interface, I will create a test that checks that the object is an instance of the interface using `assertInstanceOf`.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. The problem I'm finding now though is that as ticketAudit is mocked some of the functions that require the object and all it's properties no longer work. My error now is `Call to a member function associate() on a non-object` is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: I am not familiar with Mockery but you will need to set the behavior of those methods in your mock so that you are testing only the TicketCreator class and not needing to depend on the ticketAudit functionality.

Comment: That error is because the method `book()` is returning null.  You need to set your mocks to return something when that value is called.  Though the fact that you are doing this is a code smell, and you should consider changing your code so that you are not needing to have mock objects return mock objects.

Comment: Mockery allows to define demeter chains on mock objects, so you can prevent the error: $ticketAudit->shouldReceive('book->associate)->andReturn("whatever_needed");